# WP Woocommerce - how to change the ordering of the search products

Tags: php, wordpress, search

how can I change the order of products in the general site search? I need to order by product name.

where is the class that performs the search?

tks.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Asking a clear question will make it easier to help you. Including the work that you've done until now and sharing  the error if there is any is very important. please read this article to make sure that you get a good answer http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code in your functions.php file:

```
add_filter( 'posts_orderby', 'sort_custom' );
function sort_custom( $orderby ){
    global $wpdb;

    if( !is_admin() && is_search() ) {
      $orderby =  $wpdb->prefix . "posts.post_title ASC";
    }    

    return $orderby;
}
```

One thing to note. If you are using a search plugin like Relevanssi you will need to turn it off for this code to work. You may be able to mess with the priority of the call to get it to work but I didn't look into that.

Comment: Hi @Fencer04, tthanks for the answer, how to call this function in the search?

Comment: This code should run when you are making a search. The is_search function checks for that.

Comment: the function is not being called, it must not be called in the search form?

Comment: Ok, I updated my answer. I did some checking on my end and updated the code. The function was being called but I was using the incorrect orderby statement. I also included the table prefix just to make sure we are sorting against the correct table column.

Comment: tks, the line: add_filter( 'posts_orderby', 'sort_custom' ); should be inserted in the form template? because when inserting into functions.php appears the Call to undefined function error

Comment: You need the entire piece of code just like I have it here in the functions.php file. What function is undefined? Nothing goes in the file that creates the form.

Comment: Sorry but I'm totally new in wp when I tried to use the new function in functions.php file appears this error:
Fatal error: Call to undefined function add_filter () in /home/storage/d/40/4d/websitename/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 4815

Comment: Oh, I must have 20 reputation to talk in the chat :/

Comment: Ok, you need to put this in the functions.php file in your themes folder. You should be using a child theme for this and not updating the theme directly. It will work if you put it in the main themes functions.php file but if you update the theme you will lose the functionality.

Comment: Ok, but why wp not identifies the add_filter() function in functions.php?

Comment: That is the wrong functions.php file. There is another one on in the folder where your theme is located. It will be /wp-content/themes/<your-theme>/functions.php

Comment: Ok, now the function is in the right place, but the error appears:
Warning: Missing argument 2 for sort_custom ()
Could you explain to me where the parameters  $orderby and $query of this function is? It should not be called only when doing a search?

Comment: the search of my template is performed at product-searchform.php

Comment: It doesn't matter where the search form is. You seem to have debugging turned on. If you have an error in your functions.php file then it will show even when the code isn't being run. To remove that get rid of the second parameter in the sort_custom function. I'll update the answer. However, this function will work even with that warning being shown.

Comment: I changed the order to DESC and when I debug var_dump ($ orderby); the return variable has:

string (48) "wp_posts.menu_order ASC, ASC wp_posts.post_title"

It seems that the query order is not being changed.

Comment: At this point I believe the problem is local and is related to other plugins  or theme functions altering the orderby statement. I did a test on my system and this is producing the correct results. I would turn off all of the plugins and see if this works. If it does turn them on one by one until it stops working and that one is the issue.

Comment: You're right, to disable all plugins to function returned the correct ordering in debug. Now I need to find which plugin is performing the default ordering.

Comment: I'm glad I got you on the right track. Can you please accept my answer? I think I put a ton of work into helping you and deserve the points ;)

Comment: The plugin that is overriding the search is woocommerce, of course my friend you deserve the credit, thanks for the help xD

Comment: Thank you, you may need to put a sort order on the add_filter like so: add_filter(  'posts_orderby', 'sort_custom' , 10, 2 );